# Limiting Google App Script permission to only access files it creates

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible give a Google App Script permission to create files in a user's Google Drive, and then only have edit/delete access to those files, without having write access to any other files?

From what I can understand, the permission I need for this is `drive.file` under `dependencies.enabledAdvancedServices[].serviceId`, which is available in Google Drive API v3, but Google App Scripts only supports v2 (at least, as far as I can tell in the "Advanced Google Services" dialog).

Is there a way to get `drive.file` in GAS that I'm missing? Or has Google announced any plans to bring v3 into GAS? Or another way to restrict my script to only having write access on files it creates?

Comment: I think that your goal can be achieved. How about this method? In order to achieve your goal, how about using Web Apps? I think that when Web Apps is deployed as `Execute the app as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is used as the scope, your goal can be achieved. In this case, the script is required to be shared with users as viewer.

Comment: By the way, the scope of `drive.file` can be used for Drive API (v2) of Advanced Google services. If you want to use Drive API v3, it is required to request to the endpoint using `UrlFectchApp`. Although the version of Drive API of Advanced Google services might be updated in the future, I'm not sure about it. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: To understand what you are trying to do, you want to create a file in user A's drive through your script, and have edit permissions for that particular file, but not others? If this is the case, @Tanaike 's suggestion of using web apps could work. You could additionally create the file from your script and set it to be shared with the users automatically, would this be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @AMolina Mostly, I want my script to be able to create a script in a user's drive, without them seeing "This script can edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files" in the permission request. I would be much more comfortable with "This script can edit and delete files that it creates in your Google Drive."

Comment: @Tanaike I'll try publishing it as a web app instead, thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: There's no way to change the message that appears on the permission page, so getting what you want in there is not possible. I suggest you follow @Tanaike 's idea of the web app then.

Comment: @AMolina Thank you for your support.

Comment: @camdroid Thank you for replying. If you have any questions, feel free to tell us.

Comment: @AMolina Just to clarify, I understand I can't change the message, I want to change the permissions, so that my script doesn't have access to anything it doesn't need access to. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem is that since you are creating files, the scopes you will use (as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth)) are: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`,
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` or
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`
And all these three will result in overall change permissions that the user will have to accept (and see the message about it being able to affect the entire thing). In short, even if you can change just one file, they will see that message.